# using mod 3 in Java

Tags: java, modulo

So, I want to find what numbers between 1 and 100 are divisible by 3 and 7. I got it to work, except for one of the numbers. For some reason, 3 % 3 is giving me 3 as a remainder, but 6 % 3 is giving me 0. This is my code:

```
public class factors
{
    public static void main(System args[])
    {
        //Variables
        int integer, remainder;
        
        //Displays header
        System.out.print("Integers less than 100 that are \nevenly divisible by 3 or 7");
        
        //Loops through each integer
        for (integer = 1; integer <= 100; integer++)
        {
            remainder = integer % 3; //determines if 3 is a factor
            
            if (remainder == 0) //displays integer 
            {
                System.out.println(integer + " is divisible by 3");
            }
            
            remainder = integer % 7; //determines if 7 is a factor
            
            if (remainder == 0) //displays integer
            {
                System.out.println(integer + " is divisible by 7");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working for the number 3?

Comment: I don't believe you. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: `3 % 3` is not equal to 3. What makes you think it does?

Comment: If you really want to know for sure: `System.out.println(3 % 3);`

Comment: `I want to find what numbers between 1 and 100 are divisible by 3 and 7` if it's what you want you only want to show `integer%21`

Comment: Hmmm, can't reproduce that [http://ideone.com/owhzms](http://ideone.com/owhzms)

Comment: For my program I get:
6
7
9
12
14
15
18
21
21
24
27
28
30
33
35
36
39
42
42
45
48
49
51
54
56
57
60
63
63
66
69
70
72
75
77
78
81
84
84
87
90
91
93
96
98
99

Comment: The 3 that I was to display, doesn't display because i'm getting 3 as a remainder

Comment: I misunderstood @nachokk's comment. Will delete mine.

Comment: Please read my answer and follow my advice.

Comment: Can you post your WHOLE program here please?  Not just the snippet where you think the problem is.  I suspect there's something important that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Oh! sorry, I didn't see that, I will try putting those comments in. But, I'm still not going to get the 3 that I need to be there. How would I get the three?

Comment: I'll post the whole thing

Comment: @user2942895 What the heck. Can you run `System.out.println(3%3);` please and tell us if it outputs 0 or 3.

Comment: @Cruncher It outputs a 0 when I do that

Comment: @user2942895 ah, David Wallace found it.

Answer (score 6):

You code is actually doing

```
remainder = 3 % 7; // equals 3.
```

The best way to determine why your code is not doing what you think is to step through your code using a debugger.

All the multiples of 3 & 7 will be multiples of 21, i.e. 21, 42, 63, 84.

Comment: exactly!! great catch. Upvoting for speed.

Comment: Why is my program doing 3 % 7 and not 3 % 3?

Comment: @user2942895 One more time: you misunderstand your output. Put additional text into your print statements.

Comment: @user2942895 It is doing both as you have two statements which do a `%` and the output is the same whether you do one or the other.

Answer (score 6):

Your 3 is getting tacked onto the end of the line of text above.  You'll be seeing

```
Integers less than 100 that are 
evenly divisible by 3 or 73
```

because you wrote `print` instead of `println` for this line of text.  The % operator is working just fine, and 3 % 3 is indeed 0, not 3.

Comment: Oh!! I can't believe I didn't see that! Such a little mistake there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** outputting a `remainder` - you are displaying `integer`. So for `3` it **should** print `3`.

Make you print statements more definite:

```
System.out.println(integer + " is divisible by 3"); //  for the first `if`
and
System.out.println(integer + " is divisible by 7"); // for the second `if`
```

This should clear your confusion.

Your logic prints number divisible by `3` **or** `7`.

Comment: here is the output that I got when I ran the program:6
7
9
12
14
15
18
21
21
24
27
28
30
33
35
36
39
42
42
45
48
49
51
54
56
57
60
63
63
66
69
70
72
75
77
78
81
84
84
87
90
91
93
96
98
99

Comment: For **each** your number you can get **0**, **1**, or **2** output numbers.  Unless you "label" them you wouldn't know what you actually got. That's why I suggested to make your print statement more verbose.

Comment: I have done that, but I'm still not getting the three that I need

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code can be shortened to:

```
 //and
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
 }

//or
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 7 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
 }
```

Also I note you're not declaring a  type for your integer, remainder variables. I didn't attempt to recreate with those issues; start by solving that.

Comment: He/she is actually doing "or", not "and" here.